# How to use embed color out config

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tryed to make the embed color based on the `config.json` value

```py
with open('config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

a_color = config.get("hexcolor") #Config Text {"hexcolor": "#FFFFF"}
s_color = a_color.replace("#", "0x")

@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Some description Text", color=discord.Colour(s_color))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But my output is:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Some description Text", colour=discord.Colo
ur(s_color))
  File "C:\Users\public\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\colour.py
", line 63, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Expected int parameter, received %s instead.' % value.__class__.__name__)      
TypeError: Expected int parameter, received str instead.
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier if put the hex color already like this in the json file:

```json
{"hexcolor": "0xFFFFFF"}
```

To convert the string to a hex int:

```py
>>> int('0xFFFFFF', 16)
16777215
```

And you simply need to pass that to the `colour` kwarg

Your code should look like this:

```py
colour = int(config.get('hexcolor'), 16) # {"hexcolor": "0xFFFFFF"}

@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='whatever', colour=colour)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```